# Creating a custom repeater with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to create a custom repeater directive and pass the expression to the ng-repeat inside of the directive template.

The reason for this is to provide a cleaner interface in the html, as I am also including other directives "under-the-hood".

http://jsfiddle.net/DeanIconWeb/Cg9RC/1/

Here is my html template:

```
<tr custom-repeater="person in people">
    <td>{{person.name}}</td>
    <td>{{person.gender}}</td>
    <td>{{person.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here is my directive:

```
app.directive("customRepeater", function(){
    return {
        priority : 2000,
        restrict: 'A',
        replace : true,
        transclude : true,
        scope : {
            ngRepeatExp : "@customRepeater"
        },
        template : "<tr ng-repeat='{{ngRepeatExp}}' ng-class-even=\"'even'\" ng-transclude></tr>"
    }
});
```

In trying to make this work I kept getting the "Template must have one root element" error.

I did eventually do the following, but it's not what I really want.

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people" custom-repeater>
    <td>{{person.name}}</td>
    <td>{{person.gender}}</td>
    <td>{{person.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

Directive

```
app.directive("customRepeater", function($compile){
        return {
            priority : 2000, //must be compiled before the ng-repeat (priority 1000)
            restrict: 'A',
            compile : function(tElem, tAttrs){
                tElem.attr("ng-class-even", "'even'" );
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: "Template must have one root element" error you have to wrap the template html with one root element i.e, wrap it with `DiV`

Comment: Not sure how to make that work as I am working with a Table.

Comment: Did you find out anything new about what you were trying to do in the last year?

Comment: Actually, no.  I gave up on the idea of creating a customRepeater.  It wasn't worth the work.  Sorry

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `$compile` service to do something like this (add your other attributes/directives as you see fit before you consume the service):

http://jsfiddle.net/mQS4f/

```
app.directive("customRepeater", function ($compile) {
    return {
        //priority: 2000,
        //restrict: 'A', // This is implicit
        //replace: true,
        //transclude: true,
        //template: "<tr ng-repeat='{{ngRepeatExp}}' ng-class-even=\"'even'\" ng-transclude></tr>"
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$set('ng-repeat', attrs.customRepeater);
            element.removeAttr('custom-repeater');
            $compile(element)(scope);
        }
    }
});
```